# JTextArea in GridBagLayout wrapping too soon

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jtextarea, gridbaglayout

The `JTextArea` named `txtaObservation` is occupying five horizontal slots of its container's `GridBagLayout`. Its text should wrap by when it reaches the fifth slot, below the label named `lblObservationLimit`, however it is wrapping too soon, just about in the first slot. How do I make it wrap at the correct slot?

**JDViewCustomer.java**

```
package test2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class JDViewCustomer extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JTextArea txtaObservation;
    private JPanel panelCustomerData;

    private final CustomerData customerData;
    private JLabel lblObservationLimit;


    public JDViewCustomer(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, CustomerData customerData) {
        super(parent, modal);
        this.customerData = Objects.requireNonNull(customerData);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        layoutCustomerDataSection();
        addCustomerData();

        initComponents();
    }

    public void layoutCustomerDataSection() {
        panelCustomerData = new JPanel();
        panelCustomerData.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        panelCustomerData.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        getContentPane().add(panelCustomerData);

        GridBagLayout gbl_panelCustomerData = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panelCustomerData.columnWidths = new int[]{58, 199, 38, 102, 27, 138, 0};
        gbl_panelCustomerData.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 14, 0};
        gbl_panelCustomerData.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panelCustomerData.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panelCustomerData.setLayout(gbl_panelCustomerData);

        lblObservationLimit = new JLabel("Observation limit");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblObservationLimit = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblObservationLimit.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblObservationLimit.gridx = 5;
        gbc_lblObservationLimit.gridy = 0;
        panelCustomerData.add(lblObservationLimit, gbc_lblObservationLimit);

        txtaObservation = new JTextArea("Observation text");
        txtaObservation.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        txtaObservation.setLineWrap(true);
        txtaObservation.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_txtaObservation = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_txtaObservation.gridwidth = 5;
        gbc_txtaObservation.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc_txtaObservation.gridx = 1;
        gbc_txtaObservation.gridy = 1;
        panelCustomerData.add(txtaObservation, gbc_txtaObservation);
    }

    public void addCustomerData() {
        txtaObservation.setText(customerData.getObservation());
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("View customer");

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
    }
}
```

**CustomerData.java**

```
package test2;

public class CustomerData {

    private final String observation;

    public CustomerData(String observation) {
        this.observation = observation;
    }

    public String getObservation() {
        return observation;
    }
}
```

**Test2.java**

```
package test2;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test2 {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        CustomerData customerData = new CustomerData("Testing a long observation text that should wrap only when reaching the observation limit.");
        new JDViewCustomer(frame, true, customerData).setVisible(true);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: tente com `gbc_txtaObservation.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;` (e talvez `...gridx = 0`) []s

Comment: @CarlosHeubeger Thanks, but your comment is supposed to be in English :)

Comment: well, just three words... wouldn't make that much of a difference and just want to *show off* a bit [:-) (and don't tell me your didn't understand it)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I got it and the `.fill` worked! Turn it into an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for JDViewCustomer.java -- comments are flagged with "// kwb".  I didn't realize until just now that it was unofficially answered!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class JDViewCustomer extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JTextArea txtaObservation;
    private JPanel panelCustomerData;

    private final CustomerData customerData;
    private JLabel lblObservationLimit;


    public JDViewCustomer(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, CustomerData customerData) {
        super(parent, modal);
        this.customerData = Objects.requireNonNull(customerData);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        layoutCustomerDataSection();
        addCustomerData();

        initComponents();
    }

    public void layoutCustomerDataSection() {
        panelCustomerData = new JPanel();
        panelCustomerData.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        panelCustomerData.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        getContentPane().add(panelCustomerData);

        GridBagLayout gbl_panelCustomerData = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panelCustomerData.columnWidths = new int[]{58, 199, 38, 102, 27, 138, 0};
        gbl_panelCustomerData.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 14, 0};
        gbl_panelCustomerData.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panelCustomerData.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panelCustomerData.setLayout(gbl_panelCustomerData);

        lblObservationLimit = new JLabel("Observation limit");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblObservationLimit = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblObservationLimit.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblObservationLimit.gridx = 5;
        gbc_lblObservationLimit.gridy = 0;
// kwb set gridheight to total number of rows
        gbc_lblObservationLimit.gridheight = 2;
        panelCustomerData.add(lblObservationLimit, gbc_lblObservationLimit);

        txtaObservation = new JTextArea("Observation text");
// kwb just to help view issue
        txtaObservation.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
        txtaObservation.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        txtaObservation.setLineWrap(true);
        txtaObservation.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_txtaObservation = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_txtaObservation.gridwidth = 5;
        gbc_txtaObservation.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
// kwb fill all available horizontal space
        gbc_txtaObservation.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
// kwb change to start in column 0, adjust as necessary
        gbc_txtaObservation.gridx = 0;
        gbc_txtaObservation.gridy = 1;
        panelCustomerData.add(txtaObservation, gbc_txtaObservation);
    }

    public void addCustomerData() {
        txtaObservation.setText(customerData.getObservation());
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("View customer");

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
    }
}
```